# how to solve ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead

Tags: python, scikit-learn

i have using metrics on sklearn to compare metrics accuracy with this model :

```
# Model Accuracy, how often is the classifier correct?
a = y_test
b = df_train['Interest_Rate']
k = a.reshape(1, -1)
y = b.reshape(1, -1)
print("Accuracy:",metrics.accuracy_score(k, y))
```

but when i run it, why it become error

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[1 3 3 ... 1 3 2].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: Can you print a, b, k and y (and their shapes)? This will make easier to solve your question. Moreover, how many samples are you evaluating? And how many features do you have?

Comment: Have you tried reshape(-1,1) instead?

Comment: already tried it but the output still same